# What is the shortcut to split editor window?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to split your window vertically with a keyboard shortcut?

Right now I have to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and choose `split vertically`.

There is no mention of a shortcut here: [Splitting and Unsplitting Editor Window](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/splitting-and-unsplitting-editor-window.html)

Comment: Double shift and search vertical, it shows an option to split view the file.

Comment: +1 to @Amit's comment: it has the advantage that it shows you some other possibilities you would otherwise not know about _and_ make you both feel and look like a pro (:

Comment: Although it does not answer your question about the shortcut, a few may want to watch the video --> https://youtu.be/AHTq8nyxZSk

Answer (score 109, accepted):

File->Settings->Appearance & Behavior->Keymap
Search for Split 
Then you may define your own keyboard shortcut.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For *IntelliJ 2020.3 (Mac)* the command is now called Split-Right.
Context-Click on a tab and Split-right will create a new window to the right.

Comment: `Split and Move Right` will not duplicate the windows.